# Kohana 3.3 проблема с редиректом и логика построения контроллера

Tags: логика, php, проектирование, kohana

В версии kohana 3.3 много чего поменялось. в том числе Request::factory()->redirect($url);

Раньше было удобно делать методы типа:

```
public function action_delete()
    {
        if (Model::factory('item')->delete_item($this->request->param('id'))) {
                Request::factory()->redirect($redirect);
        }
    }
```

Сейчас так уже не выходит. Какой принцип лучше использовать для построения контроллера? Мне казалось что `action_index()` и под ним остальные рабочие экшны довольно удобно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function action_delete()
{
  $item = ORM::factory('item', $this->request->param('id'));

  try
  {
    $item->delete();
    $this->redirect($redirect);
  } catch (ORM_Validation_Exception $e) {
    throw $e;
  }    
}
```

Comment: И, да, можно ещё проверить $item->loaded(), например. Но по мне, так проще способа не придумать. В 3.3 redirect перенесли. Можно вызывать прямо через $this->redirect().

Comment: +1, все правильно

Answer (score 0):

Да, в последней версий надо пользоваться контроллером :
    Controller::redirect($url);